# Cómo puedo insertar otro dato? C#

Tags: c#

Podrían ayudarme con el punto número cuatro de este problema?

Llevo relativamente poco en la programación y realmente no sé como puedo **incorporar un nuevo alumno**, he intentado buscar por internet.. pero no me aparece casi nada, he puesto el codigo tal cual como lo llevo en visual studio, no sé como se debe hacer, así que recurro aquí por ayuda, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Registro
{
    public string nombre, domicilio, ingreso;
    public int carnet, telefono, codigo, aprobadas;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program registros = new Program();
        int cant, op;
        registros.Lectura(out cant);
        Registro[] reg = new Registro[cant];
        registros.Datos(cant, reg);
        Console.Clear();            
        do
        {               
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tMENU");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t====");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Buscar determinado alumno a partir del número de carnet");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Modificar dirección y/o teléfono de un alumno dado su numero de carnet");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Modificar datos academicos, código de carrera, asignaturas aprobadas..");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Incorporar Alumno");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Alumnos registrados");                
            Console.WriteLine("6. Salir del sistema");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite una opcion: ");
            op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            switch (op)
            {
                case 1: registros.AlumnoX(cant, reg); break;
                case 2: registros.ModificarDatos(cant, reg); break;
                case 3: registros.ModificarDatos_2(cant, reg); break;                   
                case 4: registros.TestImpresion(cant, reg); break;
                case 6: Console.WriteLine("Saliendo del sistema"); Console.ReadKey(); break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("Opción incorrecta"); Console.ReadKey(); break;
            }
        } while (op!=6);
    }
    public void Lectura(out int cant)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite la cantidad de alumnos: ");
        cant = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
    }
    public void Datos(int cant, Registro[] reg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Rellene los campos que aparecen en pantalla");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for(int i=0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Registro temp = new Registro();
            Console.Write("Carnet\nAlumno {0}: ", i + 1);
            temp.carnet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Nombre\nAlumno {0}: ", i + 1);
            temp.nombre = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Write("Domicilio\nAlumno {0}: ", i + 1);
            temp.domicilio = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Write("Telefono\nAlumno {0}: " , i + 1);
            temp.telefono = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Codigo de carrera\nAlumno {0}: ", i+1);
            temp.codigo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Fecha de Ingreso\nAlumno {0}: ", i + 1);
            temp.ingreso = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Write("Asignaturas Aprobadas\nAlumno {0}: ", i + 1);
            temp.aprobadas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            reg[i] = temp;
        }

    }
    public void AlumnoX(int cant, Registro[] reg)
    {
        bool band = false;
        int busquedaCarnet;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el número de carnet: ");
        busquedaCarnet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            while(reg[i].carnet == busquedaCarnet)
            {
                band = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Alumno encontrado");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tDatos corresponden a\nCarnet\n------\n{0}\n------\nAlumno\n------\n{1}\n------\nDomicilio\n------\n{2}\n------\nTelefono\n------\n{3}\n------\nCódigo de Carrera\n------\n{4}\n------\nFecha de Ingreso\n------\n{5}\n------\nAsignaturas Aprobadas\n------\n{6}\n", reg[i].carnet, reg[i].nombre, reg[i].domicilio, reg[i].telefono, reg[i].codigo, reg[i].ingreso, reg[i].aprobadas);
                Console.WriteLine("Presione cualquier tecla para continuar..");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }               
        }
        if (band == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dato no encontrado!");
        }
    }
    public void ModificarDatos(int cant, Registro[] reg)
    {
        int match, resp, nuevoNumero;
        bool band = false;
        string nuevoDomicilio;

        Console.WriteLine("Digite el número de carnet: ");
        match = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int i=0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            if (reg[i].carnet == match)
            {
                band = true;
            }
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("********************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("Alumno encontrado");
                Console.WriteLine("Nombre: {0}", reg[i].nombre);
                Console.WriteLine("Carnet: {0}",reg[i].carnet);
                Console.WriteLine("Domicilio: {0}", reg[i].domicilio);
                Console.WriteLine("Telefono: {0}", reg[i].telefono);
                Console.WriteLine("Fecha de Ingreso: {0}", reg[i].ingreso);
                Console.WriteLine("Código de Carrera: {0}", reg[i].codigo);
                Console.WriteLine("Asignaturas aprobadas: {0}", reg[i].aprobadas);
                Console.WriteLine("********************************************");

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("1. Cambiar dirección");        
                Console.WriteLine("2. Cambiar número de telefono");                    
                Console.WriteLine("Digite una opción: ");
                resp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (resp == 1)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite la nueva dirección: ");
                    nuevoDomicilio = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    reg[i].domicilio = nuevoDomicilio;
                    Console.WriteLine("Cambio realizado satisfactoriamente!");
                }
                else
                    if (resp == 2)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite el nuevo número de teléfono: ");
                    nuevoNumero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    reg[i].telefono = nuevoNumero;
                    Console.WriteLine("Cambio realizado satisfactoriamente!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Pulse cualquier tecla para continuar..");
                Console.ReadKey();
            } while (band == true);                
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Ottxygen, al parecer has posteado tu código incompleto (no has incluido las variables de clase) y además creo que tu código necesita un poco de formato para facilitar un poco el proceso de que podamos contestarte. Un saludo

Comment: Si deseas, después de responderte, puedo orientarte en privado para que mejoremos tu código

Answer (score 0):

Te creé el método para agregar un alumno. A mi parecer deberías manejar los nombres de métodos que se asocien a la tarea para que no se preste confusión y quien lo lea sepa más rápido de qué se trata lo que haces.

Puedes manejar variables globales hasta aprender mejor y saber cuándo puedes usarlas y cuándo no, así no estás pasando a cada rato el vector por parámetro y las variables que necesitas.

Usabas el `while` para evaluar una condición, lo que estarías haciendo un ciclo dentro de otro ciclo aunque el `while` no iteraba nada.
Para modificar los datos otra vez usabas un ciclo dentro de otro para usar la condición y no era necesario.

En tu clase, estaban declaradas las variables sin los accesos correspondientes.  Te sobrescribí el método `ToString` para que muestres con un método que te cree los registros ingresados.
Si prestas atención, podrías ahorrar todo el código para mostrar un alumno en tu opción 1.

Por ultimo, vi que intentabas ahorrar líneas en algunos casos como en tu clase y declarabas todo en una sola línea.
Deberías intentar que tu código sea lo más legible y prolijo posible para tener una mejor compresión de lo que haces cuando alguien lo revise.

```
class Program
{
    static int contador = 0;
    static int cant, op;
    static Registro[] reg;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
            if (reg == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ingresar el tamaño del vector");
                cant = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                reg = new Registro[cant];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tMENU");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t====");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Buscar determinado alumno a partir del número de carnet");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Modificar dirección y/o teléfono de un alumno dado su numero de carnet");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Modificar datos academicos, código de carrera, asignaturas aprobadas..");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Incorporar Alumno");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Alumnos registrados");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Salir del sistema");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite una opcion: ");

            op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Clear();

            switch (op)
            {
                case 1: BuscarAlumno(); break;
                case 2: ModificarAlumno(); break;
                //case 3: registros.ModificarDatos_2(cant, reg); break;
                case 4: IncorporarAlumno(); break;
                case 5: MostrarAlumnos(); break;
                case 6: Console.WriteLine("Saliendo del sistema"); Console.ReadKey(); break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("Opción incorrecta"); Console.ReadKey(); break;
            }
        } while (op != 6);
    }

    public static void IncorporarAlumno()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Rellene los campos que aparecen en pantalla");
        Registro temp = new Registro();
        Console.Write("Carnet\nAlumno {0}: ", contador);
        temp.carnet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Nombre\nAlumno {0}: ", contador);
        temp.nombre = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        Console.Write("Domicilio\nAlumno {0}: ", contador);
        temp.domicilio = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        Console.Write("Telefono\nAlumno {0}: ", contador);
        temp.telefono = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Codigo de carrera\nAlumno {0}: ", contador);
        temp.codigo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Fecha de Ingreso\nAlumno {0}: ", contador);
        temp.ingreso = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        Console.Write("Asignaturas Aprobadas\nAlumno {0}: ", contador);
        temp.aprobadas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        reg[contador] = temp;
        contador++;
    }

    public static void BuscarAlumno()
    {
        int busquedaCarnet;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el número de carnet: ");
        busquedaCarnet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            if (reg[i].carnet == busquedaCarnet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Alumno encontrado");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tDatos corresponden a\nCarnet\n------\n{0}\n------\nAlumno\n------\n{1}\n------\nDomicilio\n------\n{2}\n------\nTelefono\n------\n{3}\n------\nCódigo de Carrera\n------\n{4}\n------\nFecha de Ingreso\n------\n{5}\n------\nAsignaturas Aprobadas\n------\n{6}\n", reg[i].carnet, reg[i].nombre, reg[i].domicilio, reg[i].telefono, reg[i].codigo, reg[i].ingreso, reg[i].aprobadas);
                Console.WriteLine("Presione cualquier tecla para continuar..");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Dato no encontrado!");
    }
    static void MostrarAlumnos()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reg[i].ToString());
        }
    }
    static void ModificarAlumno()
    {
        int match, resp, nuevoNumero;
        string nuevoDomicilio;

        Console.WriteLine("Digite el número de carnet: ");
        match = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            if (reg[i].carnet == match)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("********************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("Alumno encontrado");
                Console.WriteLine("Nombre: {0}", reg[i].nombre);
                Console.WriteLine("Carnet: {0}", reg[i].carnet);
                Console.WriteLine("Domicilio: {0}", reg[i].domicilio);
                Console.WriteLine("Telefono: {0}", reg[i].telefono);
                Console.WriteLine("Fecha de Ingreso: {0}", reg[i].ingreso);
                Console.WriteLine("Código de Carrera: {0}", reg[i].codigo);
                Console.WriteLine("Asignaturas aprobadas: {0}", reg[i].aprobadas);
                Console.WriteLine("********************************************");

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("1. Cambiar dirección");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Cambiar número de telefono");
                Console.WriteLine("Digite una opción: ");
                resp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (resp == 1)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite la nueva dirección: ");
                    nuevoDomicilio = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    reg[i].domicilio = nuevoDomicilio;
                    Console.WriteLine("Cambio realizado satisfactoriamente!");
                }
                else if (resp == 2)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite el nuevo número de teléfono: ");
                    nuevoNumero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    reg[i].telefono = nuevoNumero;
                    Console.WriteLine("Cambio realizado satisfactoriamente!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Pulse cualquier tecla para continuar..");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
    public class Registro
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Nombre: { nombre}, Direccion: {domicilio}, Ingreso: {ingreso}, Materias aprobadas: {aprobadas}";
        }
        public Registro()
        {

        }
        public Registro(string nombre, string domicilio, string ingreso, int carnet, int telefono, int codigo, int aprobadas)
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.domicilio = domicilio;
            this.ingreso = ingreso;
            this.carnet = carnet;
            this.telefono = telefono;
            this.codigo = codigo;
            this.aprobadas = aprobadas;
        }

        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string domicilio { get; set; }
        public string ingreso { get; set; }
        public int carnet { get; set; }
        public int telefono { get; set; }
        public int codigo { get; set; }
        public int aprobadas { get; set; }
    }
}
```